# Fourier Expressions

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, power-series, fourier-series

In the Fourier series, what are all the ways we can express:

- $\displaystyle\sin\left(\frac{n\cdot\pi}2\right)$
- $\displaystyle\cos(n\cdot\pi)$

I know we can express

- as $(-1)^{(n+1)}$, and
- as $(-1)^n$.

What other forms are there?
I have seen a question where there has been a $\cos(n\cdot\pi)$, which when put back in the series had been changed to $\cos((2m+1)x)$.
Could somebody explain this please?

Comment: I was writing the title, but couldn't think how to phrase the question, so I typed in random letters to fill the space whilst I wrote my question in detail.

Then I posted the question without remembering to edit the title!

Comment: It's edited now. Thankyou @ADG

Comment: Aren't those constants?

Comment: Your question is very vague. What question are you referring to?

Comment: In my question I have calculated A_n=(2/(n*pi))(sin((pi*n)/2)).
I need to put change this back into series form. I would of changed the sin((pi*n)/2) to (-1)^(n+1), but the solution has changed it to 2*(-1)^n/((2n+1)*pi)*cos((2n+1)*x)).
I would like to know where the 2n+1 has come from.

Comment: That would probably had been a series in which all even term are zero for example $\sum1-(-1)^{n+1} \cos n\pi = \sum_{odd} \cos ((2m+1)\pi)$